# Are there any tools to perform a security analysis against .net desktop assemblies and excutables?

Tags: security, assemblies, static-analysis, fxcop, gendarme

Are there any tools to perform a security analysis against .net desktop assemblies and excutables? I used FXCOP and Gendarme but i think they are not sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of tools that could be used for security scanning your application. These include:

- [HP Fortify](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1338812#.Usk6z_RDsic)
- [Microsoft CAT .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19968)
- [VeraCode Code Security](http://www.veracode.com/products/static)
- [Resharper & Resharper CLI](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [Coverity Security Analyzer](http://www.coverity.com/products/security-advisor.html)

CAT .NET and Veracode act directly on the binaries. the others parse the code as far as I can tell.

Here's [an introductory short movie about CAT .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/gg675009.aspx). To run it from the commandline, you can call the executable from:

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\CAT.NET`

The syntax is as follows:

> `catnetcmd.exe /file:wildcardexpression /search:pathtodependencies`

Note that CAT .NET features a limited set of rules It should be used in conjuction with CodeAnalysis (FxCop) and though it will find additional issues it is by far not as complete as some of the other tools in the list.

Comment: Do those tools work with the assemblies or with the coed itself?

Comment: I can see that all of them are working on codes only, is this right?

Comment: Great, regarding CAT.NET, I can't find a resource to how to use it,specially, against a desktop application. any recommendations, i really appreciate your help